# UWP C# Store and Load Serial Device Information

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port, uart, windows-iot-core-10

I would like to find out how to store & load `serial deviceinformation`.
I have referred to [UWP Serial Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/tree/develop/Samples/SerialUART) and tested the serial to RS485.

I am using a FTDI USB to UART-RS485 converter on raspberry pi running Windows IoT Core. I do not intend to use the onboard UART.
So I am wondering if I am able to save the `SerialPort.id` to  `Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer` and load it when the application starts to ensure it connects to the correct `SerialPort`.

1. **How do I get the `SerialPort` readable name** like `USB-RS485-Cable` etc . becasue when i use `SerialComsDisplay.Text = listOfDevices[SerialDeviceList.SelectedIndex].Id.ToString();` it
   read the `ID` which are in code.
2. **It doesn't seems to load the correct `SerialPort` after i load it.**

Please help.
Thanks.

Saving the `SerialPort` to `container`

```
    private void SaveSerialConfig_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        localSettings.Values["SerialDevice"] = listOfDevices[SerialDeviceList.SelectedIndex].Name;
        SerialComsDisplay.Text = listOfDevices[SerialDeviceList.SelectedIndex].Id.ToString();
    }
```

Startup code to initialize the `SerialPort` when app starts

```
private async void ListAvailablePorts()
    {
        try
        {
            string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
            var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

            SerialComsDisplay.Text = "Select a device and connect";

            for (int i = 0; i < dis.Count; i++)
            {
                listOfDevices.Add(dis[i]);
            }

            DeviceListSource.Source = listOfDevices;
            SerialDeviceList.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SerialComsDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
        }

        connectCommPort();
    }


private async void connectCommPort()
    {
        var selection = SerialDeviceList.SelectedItems;
        DeviceInformation entry;

        if (selection.Count <= 0)
        {
            SerialComsDisplay.Text = "\n Select a device and connect";
            return;
        }

        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        if (localSettings.Values["SerialDevice"] != null)
        {
            var device = localSettings.Values["SerialDevice"];
            SerialComsDisplay.Text = device.ToString();
            entry = (DeviceInformation)device;
        }
        else
        {
            entry = (DeviceInformation)selection[0];
        }

        try
        {
            serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(entry.Id);
            if (serialPort == null) return;

            // Configure serial settings
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);//10 //1000
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);//100 //1000
            //serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort.BaudRate = 4800;
            serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

            // Display configured settings
            SerialComsDisplay.Text = "Serial port configured successfully: ";
            SerialComsDisplay.Text += serialPort.BaudRate + "-";
            SerialComsDisplay.Text += serialPort.DataBits + "-";
            SerialComsDisplay.Text += serialPort.Parity.ToString() + "-";
            SerialComsDisplay.Text += serialPort.StopBits;

            // Set the RcvdText field to invoke the TextChanged callback
            // The callback launches an async Read task to wait for data
            SerialComsDisplay.Text = "Waiting for data...";

            // Create cancellation token object to close I/O operations when closing the device
            ReadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            if (serialPort != null)
            {
                dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream);
                dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
            }

            Listen();

            startPollTimer();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SerialComsDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.How do I get the SerialPort readable name like USB-RS485-Cable etc . becasue when i use SerialComsDisplay.Text =
> listOfDevices[SerialDeviceList.SelectedIndex].Id.ToString(); it read
> the ID which are in code.

The property [DeviceInformation.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.name?view=winrt-19041) shows the readable name of the device.Please note that this property should only be used for display purposes only and not for finding a device because the Name can change due to localization or a user assigning a name.

> 2.It doesn't seems to load the correct SerialPort after i load it.

I reviewed your code, found out that you stored the name of DeviceInformation as SerialDevice but not a object of DeviceInformation,

```
localSettings.Values["SerialDevice"] = listOfDevices[SerialDeviceList.SelectedIndex].Name;
```

however when you loaded the setting, you parse the string to object.

```
var device = localSettings.Values["SerialDevice"];
SerialComsDisplay.Text = device.ToString();
entry = (DeviceInformation)device;
```

**UPDATE:**

```
private async void connectCommPort()
{
    var selection = SerialDeviceList.SelectedItems;
    string deviceId;

    if (selection.Count <= 0)
    {
        SerialComsDisplay.Text = "\n Select a device and connect";
        return;
    }

    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    if (localSettings.Values["SerialDevice"] != null)
    {
        var deviceId = localSettings.Values["SerialDevice"];
        SerialComsDisplay.Text = deviceId;
    }
    else
    {
        deviceId = （(DeviceInformation)selection[0]).Id;
    }

    try
    {
        serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId );
        if (serialPort == null) return;

        // Configure serial settings
        serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);//10 //1000
        serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);//100 //1000
        //serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort.BaudRate = 4800;
        serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
        serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
        serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

        // Display configured settings
        SerialComsDisplay.Text = "Serial port configured successfully: ";
        SerialComsDisplay.Text += serialPort.BaudRate + "-";
        SerialComsDisplay.Text += serialPort.DataBits + "-";
        SerialComsDisplay.Text += serialPort.Parity.ToString() + "-";
        SerialComsDisplay.Text += serialPort.StopBits;

        // Set the RcvdText field to invoke the TextChanged callback
        // The callback launches an async Read task to wait for data
        SerialComsDisplay.Text = "Waiting for data...";

        // Create cancellation token object to close I/O operations when closing the device
        ReadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        if (serialPort != null)
        {
            dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream);
            dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
        }

        Listen();

        startPollTimer();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SerialComsDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @MichealXu-MSFT I tried to saved as `.id` like this....

`localSettings.Values["SerialDevice"] = listOfDevices[SerialDeviceList.SelectedIndex].Id;`

I am not sure which method should I use when I load it. 
`var device = localSettings.Values["SerialDevice"];
                
entry = (DeviceInformation)device;
                
SerialComsDisplay.Text = entry.Name.ToString();`

Comment: @mylim, as my post above, you stored the id in SerialDevice, it is a string, you can not parse it to DeviceInformation directly.Please see my update.